# Extracting files from folder in python

Tags: python, r, loops

i have a folder with multiple sub folders.

each subfolder has a csv file ending in chance_day_speed and also has a subject Id attached to the file name.
eg 181523_chance_day_speed ... so subject id is 181523

1. I want to extract all the files ending with "chance_day_speed" in each subfolder , attach the extracted subject_id (181523) in the file name to the record I extracted the file name from, then make a master file from all the extracted csv file .

How can I also do this in R ?

Thanks

Comment: Break the problem down into parts.  Solve each part.  Post targeted questions showing what you tried when you get stuck on any particular part. For finding files that match a particular pattern I suggest trying [`pathlib.Path('string of your path').rglob('*.chance_day_speed.csv')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R the following might work reading in the data, creating a new column `subject_id` and then putting all data together in one data.frame named `master`. Untested, since there are no data.

```
file_pattern <- "chance_day_speed\\.csv$"
fls <- list.files(pattern = file_pattern)

df_list <- lapply(fls, \(f) {
  df <- read.csv(f)
  df$subject_id <- sub("^(\\d+)_.*$", "\\1", f)
  df
})

master <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

To write the data.frame `master` to file, see [`write.csv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html).

---

## Edit

To include files with another pattern in their names, use the alternation operator `|`. The first line below captures only the CSV files with `"plasma"` in their names, the second line both the files in the original question and with `"plasma"`.

```
#file_pattern <- "plasma.*\\.csv"
file_pattern <- "chance_day_speed\\.csv$|plasma.*\\.csv"

fls <- list.files(pattern = file_pattern )

df_list <- lapply(fls, \(f, id) {
  df <- read.csv(f)
  df$subject_id <- sub("^(\\d+)_.*$", "\\1", f)
  df
})

master <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: this for this, but the code is calling whole file name as subject id . I only need 181523 in the file name as subject ID.

Comment: @Adeola How come? `sub("^(\\d+).*$", "\\1", "181523_chance_day_speed.csv")` returns `"181523"`. If this is not what you are getting, can you please post an example file name where it fails?

Comment: Thank you very Rui, Can you break down the line of code so i can apply it on other filename  eg 36004001_W1D1_PRE_plasma_coo and  36004001_W1D1_PRE_plasma_fusion_calls_nhl        Thanks